# Flowing elements around each other in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a more automatic way to have data flow around an element? I feel like I've gotten really close with CSS Grid, but there are so many nooks and crannies in Grid that I haven't found yet, so maybe I just need to add a couple extra rules.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Show an element off to the right
2. Have the other elements flow around it

This would be really similar to in MS Word or Google Docs where you have an image on the top right, and all the text flows around it, but with elements instead of text.

What I have in the snippet below is mostly what I'm going for, with the following exceptions:

1. When the first `section` is short, there's plenty of room for a 4th section to be left of the `aside`. With the current method in order for this to work I'd need to change `grid-row: 1 / 4` to `grid-row: 1 / 5`, and add `aside ~ section:nth-of-type(4)` to the list of narrow `sections`.
2. When the first `section` is tall, one of the `section`s below it is well past the `aside`, so it should take up the full 5 grid columns.

In this snippet, the heights are static, but in the real world they would be dynamic. Is there any more automatic way to solve this with CSS Grid? The only other way I can think of is to detect the sizes with javascript and add classes or inline css depending on the heights of the various elements.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const aside = document.querySelector('aside');
  if (aside) {
    aside.remove();
  } else {
    document.querySelector('main').prepend(document.createElement('aside'));
  }
});

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('tall');
});
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

aside {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  
  grid-column-end: span 5;
}

section.tall {
  height: 100px;
}

aside ~ section:nth-of-type(1),
aside ~ section:nth-of-type(2),
aside ~ section:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Aside</button>
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section><a href="javascript://">Toggle Height</a></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Comment: Is using Grid for this an absolute requirement? The description of the problem sounds like it's the perfect use case for the good old `float` (along with making the elements next to the float establish the new block formatting context, e.g. with old `overflow` hack or new `display:flow-root` standard approach)

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn wow, that's exactly what I'm looking for and way too simple. I guess I was so focused on using something new I forgot about the old ways (I can't remember the last time I used `float`). I don't think I even need an overflow hack...not sure what `flow-root` does. No, Grid isn't a requirement, although I'm still curious if this is possible in Grid.

Comment: I'd say this is not a use case for Grid. Grid is about placing elements into the known places. It can automatically resize these places to accommodate the elements in them, but not rearrange their structure (e.g. making the same element take 3 grid cells or 5 grid cells depending on other elements in the same grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that the simplest solution to this problem would be using the good old `float` property, which causes other elements to flow around the given element "out of the box". The only addition needed is to make the sections establish the new Block Formatting Context, to prevent them from overlapping with floating element (as `display: block` elements do by default). There are [several ways](https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/qrORXm) to do this, including the standard (but, unfortunately, not cross-browser yet) solution — `display: flow-root`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const aside = document.querySelector('aside');
  if (aside) {
    aside.remove();
  } else {
    document.querySelector('main').prepend(document.createElement('aside'));
  }
});

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('tall');
});
```

```css
main {
  /* the display:flow-root alternative with the best balance
     between browser support and unwanted side effects (IMO).
     Other alternatives live comparison: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/qrORXm */
  column-count: 1;

  padding: 5px 5px 0;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

aside {
  height: 120px;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) * 0.4); /* 2/5 of (100% - 4 gaps of 5px each) */
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  float: right;
}

section {
  column-count: 1;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section.tall {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Aside</button>
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section><a href="javascript://">Toggle Height</a></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This answer doesn't actually work. I was mistaken about the way auto-placement works with named grid areas. I'm leaving it for reference though.

---

I'd use a simpler grid. It seems like you don't actually want a uniform 5 column grid. something like:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);*/
  grid-template: "a   aside"
                 "a   aside"
                 "a   aside"
                 "wide wide"
                 "wide wide"
                / 4fr 1fr;
}

aside {
  /* height: 120px; */
  background-color: green;
  
  /*grid-column: 4 / 6;*/
  /*grid-row: 1 / 4;*/
  
  grid-area: aside;
}

section {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  /* grid-column-end: span 5; */
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Aside</button>
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section><a href="javascript://">Toggle Height</a></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

MDN `grid-template` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Comment: If I just replace the `grid-template-columns` from my example with your `grid-template` it still has the same issues. I don't really understand how the named sections work either. Do you think you could rework that to a working example?

Comment: @redbmk I've expanded the example, but apparently I've confused the way placing items into named regions works vs. the way auto-placement places them, so this doesn't actually work how I thought it would.